# Cleaner way to do select field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Currently in my controller I've got the following:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Categories::all();
    $list = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $list[] = [
            $category->id => $category->name
        ];
    }

    return view('frontend.user.project', [
        'categories' => $list
    ]);
}
```

This is so I can populate my form using the `html()` helper, here's what I've got inside my view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ html()->label(__('validation.attributes.frontend.category'))->for('category') }}

            {{ html()->select('category', $categories)->class('form-control') }}
        </div><!--form-group-->
    </div><!--col-->
</div><!--row-->
```

What's an easier/cleaner approach instead of creating another array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pluck` to avoid any loop:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    return view('frontend.user.project', [
        'categories' => Categories::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: just a note on this, i think the lists function was deprecated in laravel 5.2. from the docs "The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature remains the same." I believe pluck in place of lists would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pluck() function:

```
    $lists = Categories::pluck('name','id');
```